# UTF-8 , Properties File and Java / Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, properties-file

I have a problem with Alfresco...I developed a custom Data List, then in the properties file I have some special characters for example :

```
acmedl_datalistModel.property.acmedl_P.title=Priorità
```

I tried to translate the ' à ' in both Html code or Unicode like that for example

```
acmedl_datalistModel.property.acmedl_P.title=Priorit`&agrave;`
```

or

```
acmedl_datalistModel.property.acmedl_P.title=Priorit`&#224;`
```

and when I visualize the Data List in Alfresco the record layout is ok like this

[image: first image]

but when I go to modify the record and the pop up is opened then is not ok like this

[image: second image]

Please I need help about that :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
acmedl_datalistModel.property.acmedl_P.title=Priorit\u00E0
```

Take a look at [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties):

> The encoding of a .properties file is ISO-8859-1, also known as
>   Latin-1. All non-Latin-1 characters must be entered by using Unicode
>   escape characters, e.g. \uHHHH where HHHH is a hexadecimal index of
>   the character in the Unicode character set.

There are some tools that can help you:

- http://native2ascii.net/
- `> %JDK_HOME%/jdk/bin/native2ascii`
- http://java-properties-editor.com/
- [Good Java property files editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164910/good-java-property-files-editor)

Comment: so, accept this answer please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work